# Same variable in parameter in mysql store procedure

Tags: mysql, optimization

How do I cache dynamic query from store procedure?
Right now I have created my store procedure like this :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_MyProcedure (
  IN UserID INT,
  .... 
)
BEGIN

   SET @sqlQuery = CONCAT("SELECT Name From Users WHERE UserID > ", UserID, " AND UserID  IN ( SELECT UserID FROM OtherTable WHERE UserID = ", UserID, " ) Order by Name") 

   PREPARE stmt FROM @sqlQuery;
   EXECUTE stmt;
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END;
```

But this kind of query does not cached. so, every time it gets more time to execute/process query.

Now I have tried some other method like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_MyProcedure (
  IN UserID INT,
  .... 
)
BEGIN
   SET @UserID = UserID;

   SET @sqlQuery = "SELECT Name From Users WHERE UserID > ? AND UserID  IN ( SELECT UserID FROM OtherTable WHERE UserID = ? ) Order by Name";

   PREPARE stmt FROM @sqlQuery;
   EXECUTE stmt @UserID, @UserID; -- here i passed same variable twice.
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END;
```

In the above case I have to pass same variable (@UserID) twice, because it is used 2 times in my query. but this job is very hectic in long or complex query. so, how do I avoid this?

One another method I tried as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_MyProcedure (
  IN UserID INT,
  .... 
)
BEGIN
   SET @UserID = UserID;

   SET @sqlQuery = "SELECT Name From Users WHERE UserID > @UserID AND UserID  IN ( SELECT UserID FROM OtherTable WHERE UserID = @UserID ) Order by Name";

   PREPARE stmt FROM @sqlQuery;
   EXECUTE stmt;
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END;
```

But above query again does not cached. so, execution time is very long. and this type of variable declared as session global variable has may be conflict with another store procedure's variable. because I have call store procedure within this store procedure and variable name should be same in another store procedure.

So, let me know what is the best solution for the same.

Thanks.

Comment: Retagged question as it has nothing to do with MySQL Workbench but is a pure MySQL optimization question.

Comment: thanks mike lischke for retag

Answer (score 0):

Sorry just posted a mistaken one,

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE yourprocedurenamehere(IN state CHAR(2))
BEGIN
SET @mystate = state;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM BLABLABLA WHERE BLA = ?');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt USING @mystate;
END;
//
```

Sorry pal, just edited my code hahaha I got this wrong

Comment: Hello javalovers, thanks for reply. but I can not understand your answer. I want to pass each parameter once in EXECUTE

Comment: javalovers, but I can't understand what you mean to say.

Answer (score 0):

A short answer is that there is no way to do it. In theory, you could identify prepared statement name with sha1(prepared statement query text), and use this as a statement handle. But there is no way to dynamically execute a statement which name is stored in a variable or in a table: EXECUTE itself is not allowed in Dynamic SQL query text.
A different question is whether you need a Dynamic SQL in your example at all, it seems like a standard SQL stored procedure parameterized with input parameters could do just fine.